# Converter DateTime to unixtime

Tags: java, java-ee, timestamp

Bom dia pessoal, alguem pode me ajudar? Estou com uma uma aplicação em Java e preciso fazer uma conversão.. Na qual é o localDate para unixtime.. Como posso fazer isso?

Esse é meu localDate:

```
for (Telemetry telemetry : listTelemetry) {


        telemetry.getInstant();
}
```

Entity:

```
public LocalDateTime getInstant() {
    return instant;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar assim

```
public Long getInstant() {
    Date date = new Date();
    return date.getTime();
}
```

Atente-se ao tipo do dado retornado que no caso de getTime é um Long representando um TimeStamp.
**`Date`** irá retornar um objeto contendo a Data e hora Atual do Sistema conforme definido pelo Sistema Operacional.

Para usar o objeto LocalDateTime você pode usar assim:

```
    LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.now(); // momento atual
    // Use ZoneId.systemDefault() para pegar o ZoneId do SO
    Date date2 = Date.from(d.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    // ou defina qual ZoneId deseja
    Date date2 = Date.from(d.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo")).toInstant());
    System.out.println(date2.getTime());
```

Se deseja retornar o objeto LocalDateTime a partir de uma informação do Banco de Dados use algo assim

```
String str = "1986-04-08 12:30";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
LocalDateTime dateTime2 = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
Date date3 = Date.from(dateTime2.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")).toInstant());
System.out.println(date3.getTime());
```

Veja o código funcionando em https://ideone.com/oivrsH

Comment: mais dentro desse meu getInstant eu tenho um LocalDateTime, preciso trabalhar com esse valor que está vindo do meu banco e ai sim transformá-lo em unix timestamp.. como posso fazer isso?

Comment: O retorno do método precisa ser LocalDateTime como sugere a assinatura do seu método? Se sim, quem receberá que deverá fazer a conversão.